# Moving from DEV to System Test

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have now finished Development but need to move the Maximo changes and config from DEV to System Test.

Is there a recommended approach/set of migration objects for this?

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately we don't have this documented anywhere.